# Column level adjustments in python-docx

Tags: python, automation, docx, python-docx

I am trying to adjust the text on a per column basis in a docx table. I have tried

```
for row in doc.tables[2].column_cells(4):
    font = run.font
    font.size = Pt(8)
```

I don't get an error with the above code, but I also am not seeing any changes to the cell texts in that column

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are accessing the correct table: The code you provided is accessing the third table in the document (index 2) and the fourth column (index 3) of that table. Make sure that this is the table you want to make changes to, and that you are referencing the correct column.

Check the scope of the loop: Ensure that the loop is looping through the cells of the column correctly.

Use the .text attribute: the font attribute only affects the font of the text, not the text itself. You can use the .text attribute to change the text.

Apply the changes to the runs within the cells: Instead of changing the font of the whole cell, you should change the font of the runs within the cell. Each cell has a .paragraphs attribute that contains a list of the paragraphs in that cell, and each paragraph has a .runs attribute that contains a list of the runs of text within that paragraph.

```
for row in doc.tables[2].column_cells(3):
for paragraph in row.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        run.font.size = Pt(8)
```

Save the changes: Remember to save the changes to the docx file after you have made the changes.

```
doc.save("updated_table.docx")
```